# prove If $k_1$ and $k_2$ are positive semidefinite kernels then $min\{k_1, k_2\}$ and $max\{k_1, k_2\}$ are psd too.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I can prove for $R+$ the function $min(x,y)$ is a positive semidefinite kernel. But I'm stuck in proving the following statement.

> Suppose $k_1(x,y)$ and $k_2(x,y)$ are positive semidefinite kernels
> from $\chi \times \chi \rightarrow R $
>
> Prove both $k_{min}$ and $k_{max}$ are positive semidefinite kernels
> too
>
> - $k_{min}(x,y) = min\{k_1(x,y), k_2(x,y)\}$
> - $k_{max}(x,y) = max\{k_1(x,y), k_2(x,y)\}$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you for your response and hint. Could you elaborate on what is $L$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich how is it possible to devide it into two sets? There could be $a, b, c \in \chi$ wich $k_1(a,b) \geq k_2(a,b), k_1(a,c) \leq k_2(a,c), k_1(c,b) \geq k_2(c,b)$

Comment: Every $n\times n$ PSD *matrix* $K$ gives rise to a PSD *kernel function* defined on the index set $\chi:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ by $k(i,j)=K_{ij}$ for all $i,j\in\chi$. Thus your two statements are true only if the element-wise minimum and maximum of any pair of PSD matrices are PSD.

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion is not true for $\max$ ([see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780613/elementwise-maximum-of-two-positive-definite-matrices)). The conclusion fails also for $\min.$ Let
$$ K_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\
2& 5
\end{pmatrix},\qquad K_2=\begin{pmatrix}5 & 2\\
2& 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
be the matrices corresponding to $k_1$ and $k_2.$
Then $\min(k_1,k_2) $ corresponds to the matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\
2& 1
\end{pmatrix}$$ which is not positive definite.